# How to implement Abstract Factory for windowing systems

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns

I was just starting a new coding project.  I may be ahead of myself, but I've gotten kinda stuck.  I wanted to implement an Abstract Factory for the GUI, similar to the example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).  However various systems have their own parameters for creating windows.  At present I have come up with the following solutions to my dilemma:

1. Create a type which varies based on compiler directives
2. Don't use compiler directives and just put everything in a type that contains every possible data member
3. Create a polymorphic hierarchy and use dynamic casting inside each window function
4. Use some sort of intermediate singleton that holds the information. This seems esp. unhelpful and would likely also involve casting.
5. Use a different pattern, such as builder instead.

My objective is to create high level interfaces that are uniform, so that creating a window, etc. is the same for all platforms.

I hesitate to do #5 simply because it seems like this would be a common enough problem that there should already be a solution.  This is just a toy, so it's more about learning than building a practical application.  I know I could use existing code bases, but that wouldn't achieve my real objective.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `However various systems have their own parameters for creating windows.` It would be great if you could provide a concrete example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it depends on the situation. But how about using abstract factory with builder (inside factory) and decorator with some default values for GUI componets, where decorator will have same interface for similar components from different GUI libraries and extends class from GUI library.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more I've realized I can use Dependency Injection to create the concrete factory first.  Since entry point knows what kind of factory it's using, that can be passed to the client.  I can't believe I didn't see it before, but I don't think that Dependency Injection "clicked" until now.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the system-specific parameters in the constructor for each abstract factory.

```
public interface WindowFactory {

 public Window build();

}

public class WindowsWindowFactory implements WindowFactory {

 private param1, param2, param3;

 public WindowsWindowFactory(param1,param2,param3) {} // set params

 public Window build() {} // use params

}

public class LinuxWindowFactory implements WindowFactory {

 private param1, param2;

 public LinuxWindowFactory(param1,param2) {} // set params

 public Window build() {} // use params

}
```